# How to obtain datasource from resource(s) in TomEE 7?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, datasource, apache-tomee, tomee-7

I'm doing java EE web application with deployment to TomEE 7 and I need to get datasource from tomee.xml. tomee.xml is located in WEB-INF directory and has the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomee>
    <Resource id="rss_db_datasource" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
        JdbcDriver = org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
        JdbcUrl = jdbc:hsqldb:file:/rss_db
        UserName = sa
        Password =
    </Resource>
</tomee>
```

I'm trying to inject Datasource using this code:

```
@Resource(name="rss_db_datasource", type = javax.sql.DataSource.class)
    private DataSource dataSource;
```

When I try to get connection from the datasource I get NullPointerException. does anybody know how to resolve this?

thank you

Comment: In what component (servlet, ejb, etc) you are trying to inject the data source ?

Comment: servlet. already resolved the issue. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

META-INF    ->  context.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context>
    <Resource name="rss_db_datasource" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              username="sa" password=""
              driverClassName="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" url="jdbc:hsqldb:file:D:/rss_db"
            />
</Context>
```

and then getting DataSource object

```
        Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
        Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
        dataSource = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("rss_db_datasource");
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `JTAManaged` to true.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomee>
    <Resource id="rss_db_datasource" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
        JdbcDriver = org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
        JdbcUrl = jdbc:hsqldb:file:/rss_db
        UserName = sa
        Password =
        JtaManaged true
    </Resource>
</tomee>
```

and also make sure the `jta-data-source` in persistence.xml is properly set.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I'm using jdbc which I want to configure in tomee.xml or even better in resources.xml and than to obtain DataSource object

Comment: looks like I'm doing everything correct. the problem occures while getting DataSource object through @Resource annotation

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to configure resources in tomee is using

1. `tomee.xml` but this one needs to be in tomee_base/conf/ or
2. you can do it in WEB-INF using `resources.xml` (just change the root tag to "resources" instead of "tomee").

The error was likely the localization of the file.

Side note:

You don't need to set `type = javax.sql.DataSource.class` at the injection point since it is the field type.